# Count of list elements that are a certain member of a discriminated union

Tags: f#, pattern-matching, discriminated-union

Let's say I have a discriminated union:

```
type foo = Bar | Baz | Batz
```

Then, I want to check how many members of a list are of type `Baz`:

```
List.sumBy (function Bar -> 1 | _ -> 0) foos
```

Is there a more idiomatic way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notice that your example is incorrect. It should be:

```
List.sumBy (fun x -> match x with Baz -> 1 | _ -> 0) foos
```

which could be rewritten as:

```
List.sumBy (function Baz -> 1 | _ -> 0) foos
```

I don't think there's a more idomatic way than using `List.sumBy` here.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on how would you define "more idiomatic". If it is a synonym of language proficiency measured, among other factors, by code performance, then similarly terse

```
List.fold (fun sum -> function Baz -> sum + 1 | _ -> sum) 0 foos
```

may be considered more idiomatic as it executes 3-4 times faster, than version with `List.sumBy` under F# 2.0.

Performance disparity that much significant has place because implementation of `List.fold` is highly optimized specifically for lists, while `List.sumBy` falls back to `Seq.sumBy` where implementation goes through ordinary `IEnumerable` traversal.

Comment: FTR, the reason `List.fold` in this fashion is faster than `List.sumBy` is because all `<Collection>.sum*` functions used checked `operator+`.

Comment: @ildjarn: I do not think so. A "quick-n-dirty" experiment with substitution of `Checked.(+)`  by unchecked `(+)` in `Seq.sumBy`
dismisses this factor as the reason for slowdown. On a list of 10000000 elements `List.fold` version is still 3-smth
times faster (`Real: 00:00:00.062, CPU: 00:00:00.062, GC gen0: 0, gen1: 0, gen2: 0`), than an
unchecked (+) version with `List.sumBy` (`Real: 00:00:00.198, CPU: 00:00:00.202, GC gen0: 0, gen1: 0, gen2: 0`).

Comment: Ah, you're right -- a little actual _testing_ (imagine that) on my part reaches the same conclusion. +1 for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would define a `count` function. It's a pretty common use case to want to count the number of elements that satisfy the given predicate.

```
let count pred = List.sumBy (fun x -> if pred x then 1 else 0)
```

Use:

```
count (fun x -> x = Bar) foos
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I'd have done instinctively.  Filter |> Length seems more natural than summing or folding.  Haven't checked peformance.

```
let count = 
    myList 
        |> List.filter (fun elem -> match elem with | Baz -> true | _ -> false)
        |> List.length
```

Answer (score 0):

...and for completenesss, don't forget the little-known fact that for-loops can pattern match.  You will get a warning about incomplete pattern matching, though, which is annoying.

```
open System

type foo = Bar | Baz of int | Batz of string * string

let myList = [Bar; Bar; Baz(1); Batz("x", "y"); Baz(2)]

let count = 
    let mutable acc = 0
    for Baz(_) in myList do
        acc <- acc + 1
acc
```

Comment: > count2;;
>
val it : int = 2
>

Comment: Runs as a console app too, not just in FSI.

Comment: Not exactly - googling around a bit it seems that it was originally a deliberate feature which they essentially deprecated by putting a warning on it.  I quite like it but perhaps that's just me!